# Can someone explain AIR Native Extensions FREGetContextActionScriptData() and FRESetContextActionScriptData() in more detail?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, ane

I have created an AIR Native Extension wherein, I have created a reusable Loader object on the AS3 side. I then pass this Loader object to the ANE to load whatever loadable file I want to load into the Loader. This works, as expected.

I would like to create the reusable Loader on the C side of the ANE. My understanding is that the FRESetContextActionScriptData() and FREGetContextActionScriptData() functions allows me to create and store AS3 FREObject variables on the C side.

I have been trying to implement these functions on the C side and and unable to wrap my head around how to do so. The Adobe help is insufficient and does not help in any way. I have tried to search for these two words with no success. Can someone throw some light on how these functions are used?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"I would like to create the reusable Loader on the C side"_ What does this mean **exactly**? Since `Loader` is a built-in Flash Player decoder of various formats (SWF, JPG, PNG, etc) how does that fit into your expected C program. **(2)** Why do you need the Loader to be on the C side?

Comment: Also this might be worth reading: (search your keywords) https://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/air_extensions.pdf